# How to increase version in lerna?

Tags: npm, lerna

I want to increase the version in my project (without publish) just by command.

So I try `lerna version 1.0.1` or `lerna version` and the version is stay the same. (1.0.0), in `lerna.json` and `package.json`.

How to make it work? I need a lerna command that increase the version in `lerna.json` and `package.json`.

Comment: Why do you need to update `lerna.json` with `lerna version`?

Comment: update the version in my project before the git-tag.

Comment: As far as I know Lerna only updates the packages of your monorepo.

Answer (score 6):

```
lerna version 1.0.1
```

When run, this command does the following:

1. **Identifies packages that have been updated since the previous tagged release.**
2. Prompts for a new version.
3. Modifies package metadata to reflect new release, running appropriate lifecycle scripts in root and per-package.
4. Commits those changes and tags the commit.
5. Pushes to the git remote.

So if there is no change in your package, it will not create new version.

> If you really want to bump up all packages version use
>
> [--force-publish](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/version#--force-publish)

```
lerna version --force-publish
```